# Projection of $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ in probability distribution in unit n dimension cubic

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

An algorithm is available that project $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\Delta_{n} = \{(x_{1},x_{2},..., x_{n})| \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} = 1, x_{i} \geq 0\}$:

$$\Pi_{\Delta_{n}} y=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\left(y_{1}-\alpha\right)_{+} \\
\left(y_{r}-\alpha\right)_{+} \\
\vdots \\
\left(y_{n}-\alpha\right)_{+}
\end{array}\right]$$
and

$\left(y_{1}-\alpha\right)_{+}=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
if \quad y_{1}-\alpha>0 ; \quad y_{1}-\alpha \\
if\quad y_{1}-\alpha \leqslant 0 ;\quad 0
\end{array}\right.$

Would it be possible to assist me in proving the algorithm and calculating $\alpha$?

Comment: For the real numbers use `\mathbb` or `\Bbb`, not `\mathcal`. And also for sums use `\sum`, not `\Sigma`.

Comment: Could you explain the problem better? Do you want an algorithm to infer $\alpha$ from $\Pi_{\Delta_n}y$? Also, is that an $n$ dimension cube or an $n$ dimension unit simplex?